# Best way to know if a folder has specified file types

Tags: vb6, directory, dir

I have a loop procedure in VB6 which explores all the folders from a specified file path.
I then need to know if each detected folder contains MP3 files.
I don't want to use the `dir` command because it takes up a lot of resources.
I've tried doing this using FSO, APIs, etc, but I can't find a solution.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4):

VB6's Dir$() function is a pretty light wrapper on FindFirstFile and friends.  I'm not sure why you think the FSO would be any lighter or faster.

The biggest serious limitations of Dir$() are that it is an ANSI function and it cannot be "interrupted" by a second search while one is already in progress without resetting the state of the first search.

What does "takes up a lot of resources" mean anyway?

I posted a Class wrapping the process at [DirLister lightweight Dir() wrapper](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=661075).

Comment: Sorry You have all the reason,i was mistaken, the procedure dir is quite quick, and now work so fine.... thanks

Comment: Glad it helped.  Check back at that link, there is now a DirLister 2 that can filter out . and .. folder names, and also has a Depth argument.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the FindFirstFile API function? It should be your best shot. There's a C# example at codeproject [A Faster Directory Enumerator](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/files/FastDirectoryEnumerator.aspx)

The VB signature goes like this:

```
<DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet := CharSet.Auto)> _
Private Shared Function FindFirstFile(ByVal lpFileName As String, ByRef lpFindFileData As WIN32_FIND_DATA) As IntPtr
End Function
```

Here's a sample VB implementation http://www.ask-4it.com/how-to-use-findfirstfile-win32-api-from-visual-basic-code-2-ca.html

You can also find a nice microsoft article on usage of the API [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/185476).